# Cannot move XAML element in grid to another cell

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime

In my Windows store app I'm trying to have two ListViews, side-by-side when the display is wide enough and vertically stacked when the display is thin.

I'm trying to do this with a 2x2 grid where by default the grid is like this

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,20">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" x:Name="FromUnitSelectorColumn" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" x:Name="ToUnitSelectorColumn" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" x:Name="FromUnitSelectorRow" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" x:Name="ToUnitSelectorRow" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ListView Name="FromUnitSelector" Header="Converting From " Margin="0,0,10,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Border BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Height="40" Width="40" Margin="5,0,0,0" Background="Beige">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding symbol}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextTrimming="Clip" FontSize="10"/>
                                </Border>
                                <Border BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Height="40" Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                </Border >
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
                <ListView Name="ToUnitSelector" Header="To " Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Border BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Height="40" Width="40" Margin="5,0,0,0" Background="Beige">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding symbol}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextTrimming="Clip"  FontSize="10"/>
                                </Border >
                                <Border BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Height="40" Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </Grid>
```

and I'm trying to set both ListViews to be stacked vertically with this in my thin visualstate

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ToUnitSelectorColumn" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="auto" />
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ToUnitSelectorRow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height">
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="*" />
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ToUnitSelector" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Grid.Row">
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ToUnitSelector" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Grid.Column">
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

but when I test it I get this exception "WinRT information: Cannot resolve TargetProperty Grid.Row on specified object."

What do I need to do to change my second ListView to another row and column? I realise that with a stackpanel I could simply change the orientation, but I need it in a grid so it stretches as much as possible.

Comment: Why not just throw them in a [WrapGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.wrapgrid) and be done with it?

Comment: Grid.Row is an attached property, so I'd try parenthesizing it - `(Grid.Row)`

Answer (score 0):

For such drastic layout changes it sometimes makes sense to simply have two different layouts and either switch them using templates or by hiding/showing containers of these layouts.